# How do i get children-attribute ID's in jsTree

Tags: javascript, jstree

First of all, I am pretty new to javascript and tried to make this work for hours.

Q: I am using a jsTree with checkboxes 
(see this link: http://nuijten.blogspot.de/2013/07/apex-tree-with-checkboxes.html)
and I want to fill in an array with the ID's of all checked children (2 level-tree, multiple roots with multiple children each)

Best i could do was to get ALL ID's into the array including the ID of the root.

```
var lmetrics = [];
$("#metrics-tree a.checked, a.undetermined").parent()
.each(function() 
{
  lmetrics.push($(this).attr("id")); 
});
```

also tried something like this within the function:

```
if ($this.children("a").hasClass("checked"))
    lmetrics.push($(this).attr("id"));
```

but guess i am doing some major mistakes

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try this

```
var inst = $.jstree.reference('#yourTreeDiv');
var checkedNodes = inst.get_checked();
```

Greets,

Martin

Comment: thanks for your help,
but i found a workaround after another 4 hours.
so, even though i appreciate your help, I can't test your version now :/